# Powershell install keeps asking for a password

Tags: macos, command-line, password, homebrew, open-source

I'm trying to upgrade my version of powershell to the latest version `7.0.1` using brew. The install seems to be stuck on disabling some ruby gems and is constantly asking over and over again for my password.  I've tried uninstalling as well and I get the same password loop over and over again.  I know I'm putting in the correct password as when I intensionally put in the wrong password I get the sorry message before it asks for my password again.

I'm a bit stumped as this point on what else to try besides removing the two folders that contain the powershell files.

How can I correctly uninstall powershell that was installed using brew if the uninstaller won't work?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Homebrew?

Comment: I'll try that now.  I have done the update reset they suggested.

Comment: @Todd thank you that fixed the issue.  Why does brew ask for your password for every action?  I know sudo can hold on to it for a period of time.

Comment: I will add this as an answer, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best step right now would be to uninstall and reinstall Homebrew. Sometimes Homebrew can be damaged and uninstalling and reinstalling it from the system will fix that.